# SharePoint Online - Possible to update ID column value in a list for an existing item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, updatelistitems, id

In SharePoint Online, Is there a way to update the ID column(for an existing item) in a list with our value?

We have a SharePoint list where I want to update the ID column value with my own value. I just want to update it for one item as is it impacting one of our solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Even after setting the ReadOnlyField property of the field to `false` you will get an error when trying to update it:

```
❯ Set-PnPListItem -List TestList -Identity 1 -Values @{ID=20}
Set-PnPListItem : This field cannot be updated.
```

Comment: Hi - then what about this MSDN documentation - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms465809(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN   it has get set property

Comment: That is for an SPItem, you can set and get an item for that - but if you tried to save it or update to a list you would get an error. (+ this is for on prem, does not apply here). You can see there also the SPListItem.ID only has the get() method: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms414164(v=office.15)

Comment: The ShareGate migration tool can preserve and write ID fields when it's copying list items.  Wonder how they're doing it... which means it is possible, just a trade secret not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is SharePoint List Item Id is read only, can't be updated with custom value.

If you are using SharePoint Online, please check the CSOM ListItem class here:

[ListItem.Id property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee539237(v%3Doffice.15))

The ListItem Id is generated after the item was created by the SharePoint system.